# Check if a UserPrincipal is enabled

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using C# code to query an Active Directory. The main issue I'm having is determining whether an account has been disabled or not. Looking through many online articles, it would appear that one cannot solely rely on the property UserPrincipal.Enabled to determine if a user account is enabled or not. Fair enough, as its a nullable Boolean but when an AD administrator disables an account, this does appear to get set to false. The problem I have is when I query a client's AD, I find that most user accounts UserPrincipal objects return false for this property. So when I use this code to check if an account is disabled:

```
private bool IsUserEnabled(UserPrincipal userPrincipal)
{
        bool isEnabled = true;

        if (userPrincipal.AccountExpirationDate != null)
        {
            // Check the expiration date is not passed.
            if (userPrincipal.AccountExpirationDate <= DateTime.Now)
            {
                Log.DebugFormat("User {0} account has expired on {1}", userPrincipal.DisplayName, userPrincipal.AccountExpirationDate.Value);
                isEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        if (userPrincipal.IsAccountLockedOut())
        {
            isEnabled = false;
            Log.DebugFormat("User {0} account is locked out", userPrincipal.DisplayName);
        }

        if (userPrincipal.Enabled != null)
        {
            isEnabled = userPrincipal.Enabled.Value;
            Log.DebugFormat("User {0} account is Enabled is set to {1}", userPrincipal.DisplayName, userPrincipal.Enabled.Value);
        }

        return isEnabled;
}
```

Most accounts appear disabled because of the `userPrincipal.Enabled` check.

However, if I leave this out and just rely on the account expiration date and the account lockout properties, then I may miss someone who is disabled using the checkbox in Active Directory which simply disables the account - without setting the account expiration date.

All the accounts where enabled returns false are actually active accounts who can log in to the domain.

How do you check if an account is actually enabled or not?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue, and was equally perplexed!

I initially was using a `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` to search for disabled users.  The status of an AD user record (re: disabled, locked out, password expiry, etc) is stored within the UserAccountControl property.  You could pass in a filter to the DirectorySearcher to locate, lets says, disabled accounts by specifying the UserAccountControl property as part of the filter.

I was never fond of this approach as it amounted to using a magic string and some magic numbers in order to build the query;  for example, this is the filter used to locate disabled accounts:

```
 var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
            {
                Filter = "(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)",
                PageSize = 50
            };
```

When I switched over to using the UserPrincipal, I was thrilled to see this nice handy "Enabled" property right on the class..  At least until I realized it didn't return the same value that the DirectorySearcher filter would return.

Unfortunately, the only reliable way that I could find to determine if the account was actually enabled was to dig into the underlying DirectoryEntry object, and go inspect the UserAccountControl property directly, ie:

```
var result = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
var uac = (int)result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"].Value;
var isEnabled = !Convert.ToBoolean(uac & 2);
```

Note - the UserAccountControl property is a "flags" enum;  all possible values for the UserAccountControl property can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772300(v=vs.85).aspx

I ended up building the above snippet into a little extension method;  fortunately doing this extra work to retrieve the UserAccountControl property didn't noticeable slow down my AD queries.

Comment: See here for some of the constants of ADS_USER_FLAG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/identity-lifecycle-manager/ms696026(v=vs.85)

Comment: I suggested an edit for this answer because you can't use round brackets to retrieve value from a collection. A pair of square brackets should be used. As follows: `(int)result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"];` I don't know why it is rejected.

Comment: Quite right @Lionet;  I've applied the edit - not sure why your change was rejected.  Thanks for taking the time to comment and improving the answer!

Comment: I think you forgot to gather the value property: (int)result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"].Value; instead of (int)result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"]; Please correct.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution by expanding the result and going to the base and expanding the base. You will see the **enabled** property there. Then I right click the expression and add to watch and copy the watch expression to my code.

```
  using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xyz.com", "Administrator", "xyz123"))
        {
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
             foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                  DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DrectoryEntry;
             foreach (String key in de.Properties.PropertyNames)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(key + " : " + de.Properties[key].Value);
                }
               Console.WriteLine("Enabled: "    +((System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthenticablePrincipal)(result)).Enabled);
               Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
                    }
                 }
             }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

`((System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthenticablePrincipal)(result)).Enabled`
is working fine to get the **enabled** true or false in the list of users.

Comment: Getting the Enabled status like this seemed to have the same inaccurate result as userPrincipal.Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what works for me in one of my applications.  Here is a snippet from my application:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com"))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Doe, John"))
    {
        Console.Out.Write(user.Enabled);
    }
}
```

This, for me, accurately returns whether the account is enabled or not.

Comment: I'm already doing this in my code and it still returns most enabled users as Enabled = false. Using an LDAP browser I have noticed that those who are 'enabled' have the userAccountControl attribute [NormalAccount] but those who appear disabled do not have the userAccountControl attribute.

Comment: I would be curious why some accounts do not have that attribute.  It appears all of our accounts have that attribute set to NormalAccount.  This website may help: http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm